# Thymeleaf submitting a collection of abstract type

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf, abstract-class

Given a class:

```
public class Foo {
    private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();

    //getter and setter
}
```

Where `Bar` is an abstract type looking like this:

```
abstract class Bar {
    private TypeEnum type;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And given a Thymeleaf template which is supposed to submit concrete instances (from custom fragments included depending on the `type` enum value), the following exception is received upon submission

> Failed to instantiate [com.example.Bar]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException.

Is there a way to specify what concrete class the instance belongs to so that the correct instance can be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pass somehow a type discriminator from the form to the controller. „disc0=enum&...“ with this information you could instanciate the Foo object with the help of a“@ModelAttribute“ function that uses the parameters to prepare the „bars“ list and return the „foo“ instance. This would happen before the actual merging of the „@ModelAttribute“ parameter used in the request handler method.

```
public class MyCtrl {
  @ModelAttribute(„foo“)
  public Foo initFoo(Request or params) {
     return builtFoo;
  }

  @RequestMapping(...)
  public String submit(@ModelAttribute(„foo“) Foo foo) {
    // use the inited and merged foo parameter
    return templateName;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite follow. I have temporarily pre-built the `Foo` object with the `Bar` list containing a single concrete instance (let's call it `BarImpl1`). This renders fine, however upon submit I receive the error in the OP as spring cannot determine the concrete type when instantiating the list. Could you elaborate a bit more on your suggestion?

Comment: During POST the „initFoo“ method would be called before the actual call to „submit“. Even in the „initFoo“ method you can already use submitted values, like some discriminators. Simplest case: just submit the classnames for each entry in the list. Use this information to instanciate classes in the appropriate positions in the list. Once done return „foo“. This model attribute will then be filled by spring with the „real“ request values and no instanciation will need to happen from an abstract class. I write this on my mobile so i cannot go much deeper. Else you will have to wait tomorrow :)

Comment: hmmm. It's still a bit fuzzy but i think I'm getting the gist of it. So the submit would call a method with a `Request` param to avoid spring trying to auto-bind,  where I could create an empty `Foo` and give it empty `Bar` instances of correct types, however I'm not sure how I'd pass it over to another controller action like the `submit` in your example.